# How does std forward taking rvalue argument binds to the lvaue param reference

Tags: c++11

This is the declaration of `std::forward`

```
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t );
```

How does this pure rvalue string `"HelloWorld!"` bind to `t` as an lvalue reference in `std::forward`?

```
std::string&& rstr = std::forward<std::string>("HelloWorld!");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, `"HelloWorld!"` is an lvalue. (An array of const char).

But your code uses the overload:

```
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t );
```

A C string literal can bind to `std::string&&`, by decaying to `char const *` and being used to initialize a temporary `std::string`.

Note that using `rstr` later would be undefined behaviour , since the temporary stops existing at the end of the statement.  There is no lifetime extension for that temporary to `rstr`'s lifetime, because `rstr` is bound to an xvalue but extension only happens when a reference is bound to a prvalue.

Comment: `std::string&& rstr = ...` explicitly extends the lifetime of the temporary until `rstr` goes out of scope.

Comment: @DanielSchepler it doesn't ! It would have to *directly* bind to the temporary, which is not the case here.

Comment: @DanielSchepler no it doesn't. `rstr` binds to an xvalue in this code. Lifetime extension only happens when a reference binds to a prvalue.

Comment: I have 2 questions:
1- if it's lvalue why did it bind to the rvalue overload?
2- std::string&& r = std::string("helloworld!") is r here defined correctly? and if so why the forwarding does not work since it's only a cast?

Comment: @mkmostafa My sentence starting "A C string literal" answers your first question, and IDK what you are trying to ask in your second question

Comment: Regarding the second question. why you can't return the rvalue reference through a function? why you can only bind to rvalue reference directly

Comment: @mkmostafa that's just what the rules of C++ are . But imagine you are a compiler writer faced with the code `T&& foo();   T&& bar = foo();`.  How will you know when and where to run the destructor for a temporary? There might not even have been any temporary, depending on what foo's body did.

Comment: But there is a temporary from foo's declaration or not? and by assigning the return to T then you have your lifetime bound to T so you can call the destructor when T is out of scope?

Comment: @mkmostafa `foo` is a function, there's no temporary. For example the body might be `T&& foo() { static T t; return std::move<T>(t); }`